# Android SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseExeption due to unknown error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am attempting to write an android app that extends the SQLiteOpenHelper class. Unfortunately I have an android test failing every due to a SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException.

Here is the database helper class that extends the SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public class ToDoDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// must be incremented upon schema change
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todo.db";

private final Context mContext;

public ToDoDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
    // database already exists
    if(dbFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    // Create a table to hold our labels
    final String SQL_CREATE_LABEL_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TaskLabel.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            TaskLabel._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            TaskLabel.COLUMN_LABEL + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
            " );";

    // Create a table to hold our priorities
    final String SQL_CREATE_PRIORITY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TaskPriority.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            TaskPriority._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            TaskPriority.COLUMN_PRIORITY + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
            " );";

    final String SQL_INSERT_PRIORITY_TABLE = "INSERT INTO " + TaskLabel.TABLE_NAME +
            " VALUES (" + Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.priority_none) + ")," +
            " (" + Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.priority_low) + ")," +
            " (" + Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.priority_med) + ")," +
            " (" + Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.priority_high) +
            ");";

    // Create a table to hold our tasks
    final String SQL_CREATE_TASK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_CREATE_DATE + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_DUE_DATE + " INTEGER," +
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_DETAIL + " TEXT," +
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_IS_COMPLETED + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_IS_DELETED + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_REMINDER_ADDED + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_LABEL_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_PRIORITY_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_PARENT_TASK_ID + " INTEGER," +

            // Set up the priority column as a foreign key to the priority table
            " FOREIGN KEY (" + TaskEntry.COLUMN_PRIORITY_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
            TaskPriority.TABLE_NAME + "(" + TaskPriority._ID + "), " +

            // Set up label column as a foreign key to the label table
            " FOREIGN KEY (" + TaskEntry.COLUMN_LABEL_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
            TaskLabel.TABLE_NAME + "(" + TaskLabel._ID + "));";

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_LABEL_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_PRIORITY_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_INSERT_PRIORITY_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TASK_TABLE);
}

// this function to be implemented if DATABASE_VERSION is incremented (i.e. if schema changes)
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
}
}
```

Below is the test that calls the class:

```
@Test
public void testCreateDb() throws Throwable {

    mContext.deleteDatabase(ToDoDbHelper.DATABASE_NAME);

    SQLiteDatabase db = new ToDoDbHelper(
            mContext).getWritableDatabase();

    // make sure the database is open
    assertEquals(true, db.isOpen());
```

The exception occurs on this line:

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = new ToDoDbHelper(
            mContext).getWritableDatabase();
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error 
(code 14): Could not open database
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:207)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:191)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:571)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
at com.todo.group1.todo.data.TestDb.testCreateDb(TestDb.java:47)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
```

I have tried:

1. Clearing application data
2. Uninstalling
3. Running the test on an emulator instead of my device
4. Renaming the database file
5. Adding READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions to the Android Manifest.

But no matter what I do, the exception is thrown and the database is never created (onCreate() is never called). What should I do? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are using Android 6+ (M), then you probably should try to request permissions at runtime.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Junit to do that? Usually you just mock a database.

Comment: @DmytroKarataiev that was it. I used the android developers documentation on runtime requests to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to put my comment as an answer here, as it solved the problem and can probably help others in the future:

On Android 6+ (M) you should request permissions at runtime to have access to a database. Android developers guide: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

I see you are missing a white blank in two SQL creation queries.

Ex:

```
final String SQL_CREATE_LABEL_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" // you missing a blank after TABLE
```

Please check all statement carefully again :)

Comment: That would only be a problem during a CRUD operation, though. It should not prevent the database file from being opened

Comment: Thank you, that was one of the problems that the tests revealed when I got them working.